# Editing custom module installed in VENDOR folder through a custom theme

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

I have a custom theme setup in Magento 2.2.5 where I am able to modify module files.

I know that to modify something installed in app/code i do this;
    **app/code/WeltPixel/ProductPage/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addto.phtml**

*becomes*

**app/design/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/WeltPixel_ProductPage/templates/product/view/addto.phtml**

This all works ok and my modifications are shown in the front end

However I have a module installed that i wish to change at;

**vendor/cart2quote/module-quotation-encoded/view/frontend/templates/quote/form.phtml**

Can somebody please tell me what what the path would be to modify this file in my custom theme? i.e.

**app/design/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/form.phtml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below Path for it

> app/design/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/Cart2Quote_Quotation/templates/quote/form.phtml